# HTML Email Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am having an issue with an HTML email and how it is rendered in Outlook 2007 and 2010.

There are 2 parts in this code snippet that is causing me issues.

```
    <ul style="margin-left:-30px">
        <li style="list-style-image:url(images/blue_bullet.png); padding-bottom:7px;">Bullet 1</li>
        <li style="list-style-image:url(images/blue_bullet.png); padding-bottom:7px;">Bullet 2</li>
        <li style="list-style-image:url(images/blue_bullet.png); padding-bottom:7px;">Bullet 3</li>
    </ul>
```

I have reviewed this link http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

It says that `padding` isn't compatible in `div` and `p'`, but it doesn't mention the lack of support for `li`. What is the best way to add some space between the `li`'s?

Also with the List Style Image this also isn't rendered, in hotmail it is just rendered as a normal disc which is ok by me but outlook it is nothing. Can i use `list-style-type:square;` but make it bigger and blue somehow?

Comment: You will need http:// for image urls, for a start. Emails have no "images" folders.

Comment: Thanks i am aware of that i just wanted to reduce the amount of code in the block plus i didn't want my image server to be public.

Comment: Background-image is not supported on Outlook 2007/2010, as explained by the CampaignMonitor page.

Comment: Thanks i understand that now, BUT do you know of a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use UTF-8 characters instead of images: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9600&number=128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the safest most consistent way to do lists in html email. More code I know, but it will render perfectly on all major clients.

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top">&bull;
    </td>
    <td valign="top" height="30">List Item 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top">&bull;
    </td>
    <td valign="top" height="30">List Item 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" valign="top">&bull;
    </td>
    <td valign="top" height="30">List Item 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `&bull;` are in separate table cells so that if you have a multi-line list item, the bullet and 'padding' remain in the correct position. If you want a different bullet type, just find a character in the ascii table to use in place of the `&bull;`. You could also use an image...

Comment: Thanks John after the lack of response that i got here i went back to tables for it. tried a few other things but after just testing it with a table it works perfectly. I am just not a huge fan of tables LOL bvut i guess in HTML email it is a must

Answer (score 0):

If you're making emails and you want them to work on all email clients, use tables and set widths - if you want to make it responsive that's a whole other ballgame and will only work with most email clients.

John has given the correct and most accurate answer for this example - but if you are making html emails then make sure you leave any web design mentality at home as it's more of a hindrance to presume that most things will work the same. Email's another world man. Good luck!